# implementing hapi-joi conditional schema

Tags: hapi.js, joi

I would like a schema for query wherein if `id` is present then any other params that might be present are ignored. However, if `id` is not present, then validation conditions apply wherein some params are `required`. In other words, something like so

```js
query: {
    id: Joi.number()
        .description("record id. All other query params are ignored if id is provided.")
        .integer()
        .positive()
        .optional(),

    everythingElse: {
        foo: Joi.string()
            .required(),

        bar: Joi.string()
            .required(),

        baz: Joi.string()
            .optional(),

        qux: Joi.string()
            .optional()
    }
}
```

Is the above possible? Reading `Joi` syntax, it seems I will have to put a `when('id', {is: Joi.number().positive().integer(), then: Joi.optional(), otherwise: Joi.required() })` clause in every the definition of every *required* param.

Comment: Other parameters `everythingElse`  do you want this only from the query parameter or can take from payload?

Comment: You can refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467550/joi-multiple-when-condition